# how to hide form action from user

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to hide form action from browser. 
is there any way to hide this?

```
<form action='http://mydomain /secure/resetPassword' method='post'>
<input required type='password'  name='pss''>
<input value='change'  type='submit' >
</form>
```

There must be some tricks. I've searched a lot but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: No you cannot hide attributes.

Comment: Why would one want to do that? The web is an open environment at least still in most parts. Let's not start obfuscation here too, just to "protect intellectual property".  Please! My experience: 99,9% of all attempts to close source for protection reasons is motivated by the programmer being ashamed of his/her code.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no practical way to hide the action from the user. Even if you figure out a way to hide it here and use JavaScript to set the action at some point later, the user can always look at the network request and see what data you're posting and where you're posting it to. So don't even bother.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hide the form action from the browser. Is there any way to hide
>   this?

Yes. But this won't add security, just obscurity. Have no action at all and post the form to the same page, then let server logic *initially* inspect the POST and forward it on to your processing page behind the scenes on the server side.

**Going a step futher**

To be frustrating for attackers, have a resource load on the form page with a changing URI, e.g. `<img src="validImage.png?nonce=892489">` so the attacker has to GET the form page, extract the image URL, GET that so the server notes that this has been separately requested, then POST (An advanced form of this is called CAPTCHA). It's sometimes fun to cause frustration like this, but it's just frustration, *not* security.